# Mongodb: Making a field the result of an operation in a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to include fields operations in query with MongoDB ?

My documents contain a 'start_time' and a 'duration' fields, and I want get all documents that are style active (where 'now' is lower than 'start_time' + 'duration').

The PostgreSQL equivalent is :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
    WHERE start_time + (INTERVAL '1 min' * duration)) > current_timestamp
```

Is it possible with a simple query in MongoDB or should I use aggregation pipelines to get the same result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `current_timestamp` here is an external variable, then this was not even a good way to represent this in SQL.

The correct way would have been to do the "reverse" that and rather than make the database recalculate the "start_time" value, alter your input value by the interval by subtracting the duration and make the database search for **"indexed values"** that are **"greater than"** the time being searched for.

Exactly therefore how you should be doing it with MongoDB, with JavaScript example in lieu of a chosen language. Easy enough to understand:

```js
var duration = 5;   // 5 minutes
var current_timestamp = new Date();

var altered_time = new Date( 
    current_timetamp.valueOf() - ( 1000 * 60 * duration )
);

db.collection.find({ "start_time": { "$gt": altered_time } })
```

So really, as would be the same with SQL form, doing the comparison that way around is the most optimal way to do it.

For the insane, or if you really did need to compare two fields in a document, then the non-optimal way to do it is with the aggregation pipeline which also cannot use an index to resolve it:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "doc": "$$ROOT",
        "matched": {
            "$gt": [
                { "$add": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$start_time", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    1000 * 60 * duration
                ]},
                current_timestamp.valueOf()
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "matched": true } }
])
```

Not a good way to do that, but neither was the SQL as you wrote it.

---

So where duration is a field in the current document, then just address differently:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "doc": "$$ROOT",
        "matched": {
            "$gt": [
                { "$add": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$start_time", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    { "$multiply": [ 1000 * 60, "$duration" ] }
                ]},
                current_timestamp.valueOf()
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "matched": true } }
])
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't meet my requirements: the 'duration' is not a global variable, but a field that is different for each record.

Comment: @Cédric then interpose the variable with the field name and the same date math, which is exactly what I said. It's not ideal but neither is the SQL. BTW. Downvote was here when I came along, but that's what you'll get for posting "transpose my SQL" without showing some effort to attempt something. Just for future reference.

Comment: I known my approach is not ideal, but it a first step to make a Proof of concept and learn about MongoDB. Thanks for your advices. You're right: mapping the SQL logic is not the finality, but just one step in my migration process. Next steps are to really integrate the no-sql spirit.